# How to Load FrameworkElement

Tags: wpf

I am writing a test. I parse xaml to get elements using **XamlReader.Parse** method

```
<StackPanel x:Name='Element1'>
    <ContentControl x:Name='Element6'>
        <Button x:Name='Element7'>
            <Label x:Name='Element8' />
        </Button>
    </ContentControl>
    <Button x:Name='Element2' />
    <FrameworkElement x:Name='Element3' />
    <Button />
    <DockPanel x:Name='Element4' />
    <FrameworkElement x:Name='Element5' />
    <FrameworkElement />
</StackPanel>
```

Next I want to iterate each visual element. I use **VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount** and **VisualTreeHelper.GetChild** methods.
**VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount** for root StackPanel returns 7 and it is right. But for ContentControl(Element 6) **VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount** returns 0.

I checked IsLoaded property and it had 'false' value. It means that ContentTemplate for ContentControl doesn't loaded.

I want to know, how I can initiate the loading of control.

Comment: I believe you could also just wait for the `ContentControl.Loaded` event - assuming something is eventually loading into the control

Comment: @Charleh, no. I also thought about it. But parsed elements will not be loaded until they are displayed in the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I put root element to the Window and invoked Show method.

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel x:Name='Element1'>
        <... />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

After that **VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount** and **VisualTreeHelper.GetChild methods** returns correct values for each element

Comment: I found the better solution. I just invoked Arrange method with not empty sized Rect.